# Is there any way to connect a local server hosted on my laptop to be accessible via mobile network?

Tags: android, networking, server, localhost, client-server

I have developed an app which connects to localhost server running on my laptop. The app was working fine when I used Android Virtual Device Manager to run it. But when I run it on a separate device on mobile network, it won't connect to the server. Is there a way to connect to the server from other networks?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect with your localhost server running in your laptop from your mobile device you need to do two things:

- Connect your android device with the same local network (wifi) which is connected to your laptop.
- Change the Url used in your code in order to connect to the server. You have to use your desktop IP address assigned by the router.
  That's it.

Comment: The problem is I do not want to connect both the devices to same local network.

Comment: Can you use a VPN?

@Alberto Can you access the laptop from the laptop itself (without virtual machines but just by the code, with only one app?). Similar to localhost but actually going through the network (going to the router to check the connection)?

Comment: @utkarshverma I don't know the reason you don't want to connect both devices to the same local network, but you can deploy your server in a PaaS with free pricing (like heroku or Now (zeit.com)) and connect your app to that server. My two cents